# unable to zoom in pdf file inside iframe

Tags: php, pdf, iframe

We are trying to zoom pdf file to 50 % inside the iframe, in which we are calling the file. But despite trying all the codes given in stackoverflow and other forums, its not working. Here is the code i'm using.

```
<iframe src="file1.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0#zoom=50%" style="position:absolute;left:10%; height:100%; top:0; bottom:0; width:80%;"></iframe>
```

Any ideas on how to get this done.

Comment: Two `#` signs in the URL? Really?

Answer (score 0):

Note that much of a clients setting is controlled by the browser, thus not all browsers use those #tags directives the same way. So for example the zoom can be overridden by

`Open PDFs to last viewed location when you reopen files`

However it is best to set the fit or zoom (depending on browser) first, than try to override toolbar `&` other peripheral settings. But the PDF will still print at 100% as that's a separate setting.

So here, although not respected by every viewer, I changed my settings to display PDF in iFrame (normally it is off) and also not keep zoom settings.

```
<iframe src="example.pdf#zoom=50%&navbar=0&toolbar=0" style="position:absolute;left:10%; height:100%; top:0; bottom:0; width:80%;"></iframe>
```

[image]

It also depends on the browsers inframe pdf viewer so here with an alternative to acrobat plugin#control , you can NOT set the #zoom or over-ride the toolbar as they are PDF viewer user controls essential for save, print or annotate.

[image]

If the browser has iFrames off to avoid stupid adverts etc then its a good idea to include a confirmation that the download is to be expected.

[image]